# SonarQube Java - Boolean literals should not be redundant - True/Null

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the followin snippet inside a method:

```java
public void foo(Bar bar){
    this.setSomeField(bar.equals(somePredefinedObject) ? null : true);
}
```

Sonarqube complains about using the literal `true` in there.
I feel like I can't just get rid of it so easily, because if that expression evaluates to false, I don't pass in false but rather pass in `null`. For evaluation to true, I pass in true.

Any ideas on how I could go about making sonarqube happy here?

Comment: Are you using a tri-state boolean there, with `null` for `false`? What is that field you're trying to set? The code makes very little sense without context tbh.

Comment: I don't know about SonarQube, but if your field is `Boolean` object (as opposed to plain `boolean`) maybe it expects `Boolean.TRUE` rather than `true`

Comment: @daniu I changed the code to something general on purpose because the context is hard to explain. Basically, I have a boolean field that can get set/reset from various places. This method is one such place. I have a ternary check, if the result is false, I set my field to null. If it's true, I set my field to true.

Comment: @joH1 Oh yes, it is indeed a Boolean object and that might just be the case. Let me try it out.

Comment: And as usual: SonarQube is just a dumb automat. So read the RSPEC-1125 spec, and decide for yourself if it makes sense to you (as a general rule as well as for the given code snippet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is SonarQube rule [RSPEC-1125](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1125)

The solution that they recommend is to change

```
booleanVariable = booleanMethod() ? exp : true;
```

to

```
booleanVariable = !booleanMethod() || exp;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with three-valued logic involving `Boolean.TRUE`, `Boolean.FALSE` and `null`.

Instead, I think that you should<sup>1</sup> write it like this:

```
public void foo(Bar bar){
    if (bar.equals(somePredefinedObject) {
       this.setSomeField(null);
    } else {
       this.setSomeField(true);
    }
}
```

Or suppress this particular case.

Arguably, the SonarQube rule is giving a false positive here, though it could also be argued that implementing 3-values logic in this way is a bad idea.

---

<sup>1 - It is possible that you could *trick* SonarQube by using a variable containing a reference to `Boolean.TRUE`, but that is going to make your code harder for other people to read. (Expect comments like "why the *heck* did you do that??")</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. But yeah it's probably bad implementing the 3-valued logic this way. But yes, thanks again !

Comment: RSPEC-1125 is meant "to improve readability". At least to me, the ternary operator version is more readable than the convoluted boolean expressions.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff - I disagree.  But, I guess the OP *could* turn off RSPEC-1125 entirely.